# MauiSplashScreen doe not works in my iOS app

Tags: maui

following the documentation, I defined my splash screen as following:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#0066B3" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

but it show me a black screen

[image]

I just found different workarounds but it does not works for me, for example:

- [Maui Splash Screen will not update on iOS App](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17940)
- [Custom Storyboard Launch Screen for iOS with .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkHNbrpi3ZQ)

Why it is black?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2022 connected/paired to a MAC, and I am using iPhone 15 iOS 17.0

Comment: Did you change app main page?

Comment: I did not understood your question

Comment: You must start app from your splash screen. Check app.xaml.cs file from shared project, then change it to your "MauiSplashScreen ".

Comment: Can you please check the build action property for the image file and some times SVG images are not works properly can you please use PNG images

Comment: I will try, in my android app the svg works well

Comment: This is a known bug, in Maui for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have ran into a known issue which causes iOS splashscreen to be a black screen.

[Apps have a black splash screen on latest simulators](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18777)

From [@rolfbjarne comment](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18777#issuecomment-1688427663), that because iOS 16.4+ apparently requires apps to be signed to load the launch screen.

For a workaround, you may open your csproj file and add the following code in it,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableCodeSigning>true</EnableCodeSigning>
    <CodesignRequireProvisioningProfile>true</CodesignRequireProvisioningProfile>
    <DisableCodesignVerification>true</DisableCodesignVerification>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more info, please refer to [Enable codesigning by default in the simulator](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18469).